# Google Analytics - Outbound Link Tracking 'DIV'

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, google-analytics

Brand new to this community (no rocks please) and having researched and tried unsuccessfully.

I am attempting to track visitors clicking on an outbound link via google analytics. The outbound link is 'sitting' (pardon my french) in a div and I tried my best to apply the existing resources, unfortunately with no avail, nothing's being tracked. In case you could help me trouble-shooting, that would be absolutely fantastic. In case you are wondering, I have little to no knowledge in coding/html (currently). This is the current code:

```
<div class="webinarjam-calltocation">

<div class="avia-button-wrap avia-button-left avia-builder-el-6 
el_after_av_heading el_before_av_textblock"><a class="inline_popup 
avia-button avia-icon_select-no avia-color-green avia-size-x-large 
avia-position-center call-to-action" href="#webinarjamlogin" 
onlick="gaTrackEvent('eventCategory', 'eventAction', 
'eventLabel');"><span class="avia_iconbox_title">>> Ja, bitte nimm mich 
in die Gästeliste auf <<</span></a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may happens, because your event call cannot reach Google before redirection occurs.
You may do as follow:

```
<script>
var track_outbound_link = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'eventCategory', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
[...]

<a href="https://yourlink.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://yourlink.example.com'); return false;">Link label</a>
```

Comment: PS: you may need to wait a moment before events appears in Google Analytics, I waited few hours yesterday :)

Comment: Thank you very much Lukasz. I will have a stab at it and be patiënt. I am embarassed to ask, however in terms of including it in the code of the div, would i simply add the <script> after the div or would i have to integrate it (somehow)?

Comment: @BorisTheBlade - you may add this <script> stuff whenever you want, however the best place for scripts (excluding some exceptions) is just before </body> closing tag. And add this code only once, regardless of the link elements count

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. Makes sense to me. May I ask one follow-up: I understand that the <a href="https://yourlink.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://yourlink.example.com'); return false;">Link label</a> would be applied to the actual outbound link. The challenge that I am facing given my technical shortcomings is how to apply this snipped to the outbound div as pointed out in my initial question. thank you!

Comment: @BorisTheBlade your initial code is attached to <a>, it is just inside <div>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried desperately to get it working based on your instructions, unfortunately to no avail. My code pertaining to the div currently says:

Comment: <div class="webinarjam-calltocation">
<div class="avia-button-wrap avia-button-left avia-builder-el-6 el_after_av_heading el_before_av_textblock"><a class="inline_popup avia-button avia-icon_select-no avia-color-green avia-size-x-large avia-position-center call-to-action" href="#webinarjamlogin" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Click on the menu icon', 'Click');"><span class="avia_iconbox_title">>> Ja, bitte nimm mich in die Gästeliste auf <<</span></a></div>
</div>

Comment: My analytics code is handled through the wordpress header and currently says:

Comment: <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX');
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
</script>
<script>
var track_outbound_link = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'eventCategory', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>

Comment: any help would be dearly, dearly appreciated! Thanks!